# Not showing proper parent in bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, git-branch

I am using bitbucket to maintain my code base. Every sprint we create new branch and from this new branch user creates his own branch and works on it. Problem is that bitbucket is not showing proper parent of the branch i..e from which branch this child branch was created from.

[image]

Please see the attached image. Its is showing as master rather then sprint8 from where it was branched out from.

Creating branch on bitbucket

[image]

Output on bitbucket after hitting create button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There can be some reasons for it:

- You didn't push the sprint branch so it is not seen on the BitBucket server.
- You were on 'master' when you branched or the branch command added 'master' as part of it even though you were on the sprint branch, e.g. `git checkout bugfix_DE57162_zerovalue_sprint8 master`

If it is not the case, can you provide more information on the environment were it were done: branch command, 'git status' output before branching, etc?

Comment: We are inside the branch from where we wanna create child branch. We use git checkout -b newbranch sprint8. Updated question with  example, as to what is happening when i create branch on bitbucket. It still shows master as parent. Any configuration to be changed for this?